# Linux system login: How to use /etc/passwd to filter user name again ldap

Tags: linux, authentication, ldap

I'm working for an university. I can access the University LDAP server but can't modify anything (it's readonly to me). I have several Linux machines, I want to config all the machines to authenticate via the university LDAP. (that's pretty easy, right?). Problems are:

Only a subset of LDAP users are allow to log in to the machine, (I know it can be done via LDAP group or additional LDAP attribute, but I can't modify anything in the university LDAP)
Some users may not be in the LDAP but have accounts on the machine
My thought is: use the /etc/passwd as the user-list: if (a user is NOT in the list) { he can't log in, } else { if(he is in LDAP) { check his password again the university LDAP } else { check his password againt /etc/shadow } }

Is there any solution? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For allowing only a subset of LDAP users to login:

1. If you have a way to filter them without modifying the LDAP server, then you can add the filter to your `/etc/nslcd.conf` file, e.g.:

   ```
   filter passwd (objectClass=localAccount)
   ```
2. Otherwise, you'll have to allow all LDAP users as local users and grant permissions just to the ones that you want, e.g., by changing `/etc/security/access.conf` and/or `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

For having additional local users, on top of those from the LDAP server, you'll need your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file to contain something like:

```
passwd: files [unavail=return] ldap
group:  files [unavail=return] ldap
shadow: files ldap
```

I hope I'm not forgetting something...